# Is there any way to control which policies IAM users are allowed to attach to other IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an IAM user that is responsible for distributing policies to other users in my organization. We have a set of policies that we wish to use for that, but he can still add AWS-managed policies to said users, which is not ideal.
I need to block this user from attaching certain policies to users, or limit the scope of policies they can attach to this set or pre-built policies.

Basically I don't want this account to be able to give the `AdministratorAccess` policy to any one in case it's compromised.

I know I can add conditions to IAM actions so that those actions can only be "done" to certain users or roles, but I can't seem to find a way to "filter" the policies an user is allowed to give when they have the `iam:AttachUserPolicy` action allowed.

Using permission boundaries is not really ideal, because although it works, it defeats a bit the purpose of creating this controlled set of policies. It might be a solution, but I came here to see if other solutions are available.
Using groups is also not ideal, as there is a limit to the amount of groups one user is allowed to be added to.

**Is there any way to control which policies users are allowed to add/remove from other users?**
If not, is there a solution to the admin access issue?

Comment: I would say permission boundaries are the best solution

Comment: Given the team structure's I'm trying to find another way, but if nothing seems viable that's what I'm going for. But I'll always give a chance for human creativity to surprise me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iam:AttachUserPolicy` action [supports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awsidentityandaccessmanagementiam.html) the [`iam:PolicyArn`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_iam-condition-keys.html#ck_PolicyARN) condition key which allows filtering access by the ARN of an IAM policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAttachUserPolicyForSpecificPolicies",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iam:AttachUserPolicy",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "ArnEquals": {
          "iam:PolicyArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/policy1",
            "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:policy/policy2"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I was looking for. Will test and come back for feedback. I hadn't found this condition structure in my searches yet.

Comment: It worked like a charm, and opened my eyes a bit on a few possibilities. Thank you so much!